# How to allow Access Control Header to access a remote API in cross-domain?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http, cors

I am developing a mobile application, I get my data through a remote API but my javascript program returns the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://na.lolesports.com/api/standings.json?tournamentId=225. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin ... is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: If i remember right this happens is the server side don't put the right cross domain headers on the HTTP Response.

Comment: If the API provides JSONP you should use that

Comment: if you enter this URL into your browser, a response is obtained: http://na.lolesports.com:80/api/schedule.json?tournamentId=230&includeFinished=true&includeFuture=false&includeLive=false

Also using a Chrome extension available here: https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=navclient&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8#hl=fr&q=chrome+extension+allow+origin

It works perfectly locally using this Chrome extension, I just want to do the same without the extension.

Comment: @dalu do you have an example for this case ? I am not sure if they provide Json.

Comment: @Okazari so how can I fix it ?

Comment: You cannot, this is the responsibility of the server part. Since riot manage this API ... they have to do it. If i am right, cross domain request should work on you server side. You will need a server that will request that for you.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything you can do on your end, the CORS settings for the API would have to be changed. In fact, they are specifically not allowing cross-site origins because they don't want to allow third-party access to their API:

https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/community-discussion/show/GokMZKKl

Comment: Still be able to request on server side right ? Just not from javascript.